# Report generation using For loop powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a program which generate some reports by reading .XML file and I have to generate reports for multiple files.

But the problem which I am facing is for doing this I need to run it multiple times for each files as program reads only 1 file in 1 click.

Is there any way by which I can generate reports for multiple files in one click ?

So far i have tried below codes

```
$a = Get-ChildItem "D:\Directory1\Files\*.xml"
foreach ($i in $a) 
{
    Move-Item $i "D:\Directory1\" 
    if ($a) {
      D:\Directory1\Program1.exe /run /exit /SilentMode 
    }
 }
```

As per the above code I am trying to Read files from `"D:\Directory1\Files\"` Then move any 1 file (Not all Files) to the directory `"D:\Directory1\"` and then start the Program "Program1.exe" and generate the reports and repeat it till the .xml files exist in `"D:\Directory1\Files\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your goal to copy all files from `D:\Directory1\Files\` to `D:\Directory1\` in one step and then run `D:\Directory1\Program1.exe /run /exit /SilentMode`?


EDIT:
This work for you?
0. Set location that your program work
1. Get all files
2. For each file
3. Move file to new location
4. Start you program
5. Remove the moved file

```
 Set-Location -Path "D:\Directory1\"
 $arrFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Directory1\Files\*.xml"
 Foreach ($objFile in $arrFiles) {
    Move-Item -Path $objFile.FullName -Destination "D:\Directory1\$($objFile.Name)"
    Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Directory1\Program1.exe" -ArgumentList "/run /exit /SilentMode" -Wait
    Remove-Item -Path "D:\Directory1\$($objFile.Name)"
 }
```

Comment: no my goal is to move 1 file from D:/Directory1/files to D:/Directory1/ and then start the program then it will read file and generate report then move next file in D:/Directory1/files to D:/Directory1 and then run the program and generate report keep repeating these steps till last file in the directory D:/Directory1/files

Comment: The code you posted do this steps. In $a there are all files. Then foreach file you move it to the new destination and run your program. Where is the "Error" or "Problem"? The program picks up any file in the folder  D:\Directory1\ ?

Comment: Thanks dear after Modifying some codes in last line I got my Desired Result Really appreciated you are great. Thanks to this Awesome forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic here was sound, however, one issue you would have is the script will continue processing even while `Program1.exe` is running. Thereby making it possible for it to seeminly skip files. Also your `If` statement is just check if `$a` contains data which it always will in you example. Makes the condition check mute. 
What you can do is something like this.

```
$moveLocation = "D:\Directory1\"
Get-ChildItem "D:\Directory1\Files\*.xml" | ForEach-Object{
    # Move the file to its new location
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $moveLocation
    Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Directory1\Program1.exe" -ArgumentList "/run /exit /SilentMode" -Wait   
}
```